# Can not draw model

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, lwjgl, opengl-3

It is necessary to determine whether the triangles of the model (the eagle) are inside the rectangular plane. Wrote the program, but for some reason, it works poorly. What is the reason?

`matrCoord` - The vertex of the triangle, `projMatrCopy` - the projection matrix **P * V * M**. I get new coordinates of the vertex of the triangle of the model:

```
private Vector3f getVector(int pos) {
        Matrix4f projMatrCopy = new Matrix4f().set(proj);
        Matrix4f matrCoord = new Matrix4f(new Vector4f(positions[pos], positions[pos + 1], positions[pos + 2], 1.0f),
                new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Vector4f(0, 0, 0, 0),
                new Vector4f(0,0,0, 0));
        Vector4f p1 = new Vector4f();
        projMatrCopy.mul(matrCoord).getColumn(0, p1);
        return new Vector3f(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z);
    }
```

And then I check this vertex to see if it is inside a rectangular area. I do it this way:

```
private boolean intersectsPlaneToPoint(Vector3f point, List<Vector4f> planes) {

        Float d1 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z,planes.get(0).x,planes.get(0).y,planes.get(0).z,planes.get(0).w);
        Float d2 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z, planes.get(1).x,planes.get(1).y,planes.get(1).z,planes.get(1).w);
        Float d3 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z, planes.get(2).x,planes.get(2).y,planes.get(2).z,planes.get(2).w);
        Float d4 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z, planes.get(3).x,planes.get(3).y,planes.get(3).z,planes.get(3).w);
        Float d5 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z, planes.get(4).x,planes.get(4).y,planes.get(4).z,planes.get(4).w);
        Float d6 = Intersectionf.distancePointPlane(point.x, point.y, point.z,planes.get(5).x,planes.get(5).y,planes.get(5).z,planes.get(5).w);
        return d1 < 0 && d2 < 0 && d3 < 0 && d4 >= 0 && d5 < 0 && d6 >= 0;
    }
```

`planes.get (0).x, planes.get (0).y, planes.get (0).z, planes.get (0).w` are **a b c d** components of the plane
[image]

**Must be output:**

[image]

Comment: What works poorly about it? Does it run slow or give an incorrect result? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Sean Updated question

Comment: I still don’t understand what the question is. What’s wrong? What specifically needs to be fixed?

Comment: @Sean In the screenshot, you can see that not all triangles stand out with the green color. Question: how to fix it?

Comment: So you are saying that green triangles should be "inside" the blue square (frustum?)?

Comment: @markspace No, there is a model (eagle). It is necessary to draw those parts of this figure (triangles) that are inside the blue square.

Comment: So you want the eagle clipped against the blue square?  Triangles outside of the blue square should not be drawn at all?

Comment: @markspace No, I need to paint in red a part of the model that hit the inside of the blue square